# How to perform a SELECT statement on a DATE in RBQL Rainbow CSV

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to select all records where the date (a5) is greater than 2021. I keep getting false results back. I have tried the following.

```
SELECT * WHERE a5 > "3/02/2021"
SELECT * WHERE a5 > '3/02/2021' 
SELECT * WHERE parseInt(a5) > 3/02/2021
```

I went through the documentation but don't see anything about Date format. Here are my negative results.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function from Javascript e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE Date.parse(a5) > Date.parse('3/02/2021') and NR > 1
```

or (if you click that "Input table has header" checkbox):

```
SELECT * WHERE Date.parse(a.hireDate) > Date.parse('3/02/2021')
```